# Problems with AFNetworking 2.1.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I hope this hasn't been asked here...I've done quite a bit of searching on this site but am not really getting anywhere  I've been using ASIHTTPRequest to get JSON data, but am now trying to migrate to AFNetworking 2.1.0.  I'm using the following:

```
-(BOOL)getCoordsForAddress:(NSString*) inputAddress {

    responseString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    // retrieve and urlencode address
    NSString *encodedAddress = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)inputAddress, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    // build the geocoding URL
    NSString *getLatLonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", encodedAddress];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com"]];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];

    [manager GET:getLatLonUrl 
      parameters:nil  
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            responseString = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
            NSLog(@" Success %@", responseObject);
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@" Fail %@", error);
        }];

    return YES;
}
```

However, when I execute the manager GET routine, nothing is executed, neither the Success or Failure messages are printed out.  It's as if that call is getting ignored.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any assistance!!!

Comment: Does `po getLatLonUrl` return what you expect?  Do you need to encoding this yourself?  You can pass an NSDictionary (like `@{@"address:":inputAddress, @"sensor":@"false"}` into `parameters:` and AFNetworking will encode it for you.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. I tested it on my Mac. It's working as expected. I'm passing "Ahmedabad" as `inputAddress`. but that should not make a difference here. Are there any kind of warning about `AFNetworking` in `XCode` when you build the project?

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies.  @AaronBrager, yes, getLatLonURL is correct.  I tried this address "500 Main St, Atlanta, GA 30324" and get the correct JSON response, which is here:  [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=500%20main%20st%2C%20atlanta%2C%20ga%2030324&sensor=false)

Comment: @AkshitZaveri, no, not getting any warnings whatsoever regarding AFNetworking.  I really don't understand why neither of those paths are taken with the GET function call.

Comment: @user1292943 One possibility: `manager` is deallocated at the end of the method, and the operation queue is deallocated before your operation starts work.  This seems unlikely to me, but as a test, try adding `@property AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;` and changing `manager` in this method to `self.manager`.

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks once more for your response.  I did as you suggested.  I added manager as a property, and changed the function to refer to self.manager.  I also tried removing AFNetworking, then reinstalling using CocoaPods, and still have the same result.  I really don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: I set a breakpoint inside the GET routine and looked at the value of operation at the "return operation" statement.  responseObject is 0.  What could be causing this?  I'm really at a loss...  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Well I'd expect responseObject to be nil there because the server hasn't responded yet. You have to poke around inside the AFHTTPRequestOperation before / around when the success block is called.